# How do I calculate derivative of sgn(x)

Tags: derivatives

We know $|x| = \sqrt(x^2)$, determine the second derivative

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}|x|$,

So the first derivative is sgn(x), but how do I get the second?

Comment: It doesn't have a derivative using the normal limit definition. It however has a weak derivative, a distribution, normally denoted $\delta$.

Comment: If $f(x)=|x|$, then $f'(0)$ is undefined. If $x\neq 0$, then $f'(x)=\text{sgn}(x)$ [(sign function; signum function).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

Consider the graph of $sgn(x)$. What does it look like? What kind of slope does it have?

Comment: Two horizontal lines from Y = -1 and Y = 1, so the slope is 0 but at X = 0 the slope becomes undefined. True?

Comment: Yes, this is not defined in $x=0$. However, you should already know that from the first derivative (where the derivative in $x=0$ is not defined).

Comment: In fact, the derivative of $|x|$ is not exactly e qual to the signum function, because you already need to restrict the domain to $\mathbb{R} - {0}$. This won't allow you to even consider what happens around $x=0$ to differentiate again, because while it is part of the domain of $sgn(x)$, it is not part of the domain of $\frac{d}{dx} |x|$.

Comment: Ok I'm lost, so I shouldn't try to get the derivative of sgn(x)?

Comment: Actually, you are not left **exactly** with the $sgn$ function. However, since the only point that is missing in the derivative of $|x|$ is the point at zero, using directly the signum function to differentiate is not that big a problem. You cannot say, though, that the derivative of $|x|$ and the signum function are exactly the same thing, because although they have exactly the same effect in their domains, they do not range over the same domain.

Comment: What you're left with is some function $f'(x)$ that behaves exactly like $sgn(x)$, except in $x=0$ where it is not defined. So you don't even need to consider what happens at 0 if you differentiate $f'(x)$.

Comment: If I go back to $\sqrt(x^2)$ and write it as $f(g(x))$ where $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ and $g(x)= x^2$, then can I get the derivative as $f'(g(x)) * g'(x)$ which would be $2x/2|x|$ which is $x/|x|$ then the second derivative would be using $f(x)/g(x)$ where $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt(x^2)$ which would give me $|x| - x/|x|$ as the second derivative. Or am I just going crazy

Comment: It would be $|x|/x^2 - 1/|x|$, which is a constant null function not defined in $x=0$.

Comment: ehhh thanks for trying but I'll just give myself an incomplete on this assignment.

Answer (score 7):

Considering derivative of discontinuity as del(x). Derivative of sgn(x) would be 2*del(x), as there exist a discontinuity at x=0 and a change in step by 2 units (from -1 to +1).

Note : 
This method is being used in mathematical modeling of signals. Where del(t) is an unit impluse function. And sgn is made up of two step functions.

Answer (score 6):

You know that

$sgn(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x>0 \\
      0 & x=0 \\
      -1 & x<0 
   \end{cases}$

I think you can get the derivative from there, derivate each piece of the function. Notice the discontinuity points and consider how this affects the existence of derivative at some points.